# All sorts of icons are blurry and broken looking

Tags: icon

Recently, I downloaded a VPN app. It's icon appeared as normal for a second, and then became quite strange looking. After a while, this problem started to spread to the icons of other apps as well as icons within the apps. Is this a virus, or corrupted data or what?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the name of the VPN app?

Comment: I forget, otherwise I would have mentioned it.

Comment: Is there a way you could find out (like looking in your downloads or applications folders? We can't tell you if it's a virus if you can't tell us what the name is